# How to add xml-stylesheet tag in a XML File using libxml2?

Tags: xml, libxml2

I'd like to know how I could insert the special tag

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XYZ.xslt"?>
```

in a document, just after the `<?xml version="1.0" ... ?>` and
before the Doc root element ??
I currently use libxml2 version 2.7.8

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It helps to know that this "tag" is actually a processing instruction, and you can create processing instructions using the XSLT instruction

```
<xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">
  <xsl:text>type="text/xsl" href="XYZ.xslt"</xsl:text>
</xsl:processing-instruction>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering...but i was wondering if there is any specific API is available in LIBXML2 (ver 2.7.8) to create the <?xml-stylesheet....?> tag.